# Erro 'ImportError: cannot import name pbkdf2' após compilar utilizando 'Pyinstaller'

Tags: python

Quando eu rodo o script pelo PyCharm ele funciona normalmente, mas após compilar utilizando pyinstaller ele apresenta o erro abaixo. Faz sentido? ele funcionar normalmente no editor e logo após compilar ele retornar erros?

Primeiro ele aparecia o erro abaixo e eu importei ele e resolveu.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'secrets'
```

Depois ele apareceu o erro:
`ImportError: cannot import name pbkdf2`

Mas não resolveu instalando e importando.

Código onde é gerado o erro ao compilar:

```
import oracledb
import secrets
from integracaobd import DataBase


def listaprodutos():
    listcodprod = []
    for cod in DataBase.produtos_integrados():
        listcodprod.append(cod['CODPROD'])

    oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir='oracle_19.9')
    con = oracledb.connect(user="CECOTI", password='PASSWORD', dsn="IP")
    bdqry = con.cursor().execute(f"""SELECT P.CODPROD, P.DESCRICAO, 
                                 (SELECT PVENDA FROM PCTABPR V WHERE V.CODPROD = P.CODPROD AND NUMREGIAO = 2) AS PVENDA, 
                                 (SELECT (PKG_ESTOQUE.ESTOQUE_DISPONIVEL(P.CODPROD, '1', 'V')) 
                                 FROM PCEST E WHERE E.CODPROD = P.CODPROD AND CODFILIAL = '1') AS QTDISP 
                                 FROM PCPRODUT P 
                                 WHERE CODPROD IN {tuple(listcodprod)}""")

    lista = []

    for q in bdqry:
        lista.append({'CODPROD': q[0], 'DESCRICAO': q[1], 'PRECO': q[2], 'QTDISP': q[3]})
    con.close()
    return lista

    for q in bdqry:
        dados = {'CODPROD': q[0], 'DESCRICAO': q[1], 'PRECO': q[2], 'QTDISP': q[3]}
    con.close()
    return dados
```

Então ele gera o erro acima quando eu tento compilar com `pyinstaller -w initializer.py` gerando erro `ImportError: cannot import name pbkdf2`. Eu não utilizei esse módulo em nenhum momento do código, talvez o próprio módulo `oracledb` utilize e eu não consegui resolver.

Também tentei incluir a pasta site-packages onde ficam todas as bibliotecas externas e também não resolveu.

Tentei trocar o módulo interpretador do oracle para o cx_oracle e gera outro erro.

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido!
Após muitas pesquisas encontrei um tópico que ensina a corrigir o erro no link a [seguir](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5572)

```
import sys
import os

instantclient_dir = 'instantclient_19_10'
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    instaclient_dir = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, instantclient_dir)
    # Add Oracle Client library directory to PATH
    os.environ['PATH'] = instantclient_dir + os.path.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']

import cx_Oracle
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=instantclient_dir)
    print("Hello world!")
```